# Print Array in Text View

Tags: java, android, arrays, textview

I have small challenge that I do not know how to overcome. 
From a Firebase Database, I collect some data and I will like to print it out inside a "textview".

I have the flowing functional method

```
 private void collect_comments(Map<String,Object> users) {

        ArrayList<String> fetch_title = new ArrayList<>();

        //iterate through each user, ignoring their UID
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : users.entrySet()) {

            //Get user map
            Map title = (Map) entry.getValue();
            Map msg = (Map) entry.getValue();
            //Get phone field and append to list
            fetch_title.add((String) title.get("post_title"));// Student X says: 
            fetch_title.add((String) msg.get("message")); // the message

            post_update.setText(fetch_title.toString());


        }//end of for loop
```

My problem is the current output:

```
Student Billy Bob says: Hello World Student Jony Jhon says: Hello Back Student Ben Dover says: I can not read this
```

Help me please to format my output into:
Student Billy Bob says: Hello World
Student Jony Jhon says: Hello Back 
Student Ben Dover says: I can not read this

As you can see, "Student Billy Bob says: " represents the "post_title" and "Hello World" is the "message". I will like to insert a new line after every "post_title" +"message".

I manage something close with the fallowing:

```
for(String s : fetch_title) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

The only problem is that I do not know how to transpose the System.out.println into "textview".

I tried also with:

```
for(String s : fetch_title) {
                post_update.setText(s);
            }
```

The output is only one line (Student Billy Bob says: Hello World) given that I added the "singleline=false" and "minlines=1" into my xml.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvValue"
    android:layout_width="408dp"
    android:layout_height="502dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:minLines="1"
    />
```

Please help me with this. Where I do wrong? The java? the XML?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are asking, to add a new line character add "\n" to the system.out.println or setText

```
System.out.println(s + "\n");
```

or

`post_update.setText(s + "\n");`

Comment: Works, but display only one line. not all.

Comment: THIS IS WORKING:  fetch_title.add((String) title.get("post_title") + msg.get("message")+ "\n");

            post_update.setText(fetch_title.toString());